# jQuery DataTable : Browser is becoming unresponsive while downloading 16K rows to CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, datatables

I'm using jQuery Datatable to display data. I am trying to download the data in csv format. It is working fine for around 14-15K rows of data but the browser is being unresponsive when the data is exceeding 16K rows. Here is the code:

*JS Code*

```
function createDataTable(data) {
    selectedDealer = [];
    allDealerData = data;
    table = null;
    table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
        "dom" : "Bfrtip",
        "data" : data,
        "columns" : [ {
            "data" : "id"
        }, {
            "data" : "dlrName"
        }, {
            "data" : "dlrName"
        }, {
            "data" : "pyramid"
        }, {
            "data" : ""
        } ],
        'columnDefs' : [ {
            'targets' : 0,
            'orderable' : false,
            'searchable' : false,
            'className' : "col-hidden",
            'render' : function(data, type, full, meta) {
                return data;
            }
        }, {
            'targets' : 1,
            'render' : function(data, type, full, meta) {
                return data.substring(0, 11);
            }
        }, {
            'targets' : 2,
            'render' : function(data, type, full, meta) {
                return data.substring(12);
            }
        }, {
            'targets' : 4,
            'width' : '0%',
            'render' : function(data, type, full, meta) {
                return 'Y';
            }
        } ],
        stateSave : true,
        buttons : [ {
            extend : 'csv',
            exportOptions : {
                columns : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
            }
        } ]
    });
    addTableEvents();
}
```

Is there any solution to avoid this? Please help.

Comment: yes there is. [ajax loading](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html). write a server side script to deliver the data as needed so it's not all loaded all at once.

Comment: The best way to avoid this problem is to paginate your data i.e load may be 100 rows at a time. And dynamically load other pages based on the request

Comment: Another option is to implement infinit scroll, like feed of facebook...and show 20 in 20.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Can you please write this as an answer so that I can accept it. :)